# Angular code not run on Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I have some angular code, no major stuff just some ajax and ng-repeats and ng-clicks. The issue is the code is running perfectly on my computer IE, firefox, chrome, edge. It even works on Android chrome. But I get curlybraces displayed when I'm trying on my Android stock browser. 
FYI I'm using a Samsung Grand 2 if it helps.

Any idea why this happens?
Also on another note in order to come to this page, the browser goes through some other pages which uses angular and they seem to be working fine on the said browser.

[image]

Comment: looks like there is some error. check console for errors

Comment: Hi, but I don't get this on any other browsers. Laptop or mobile device. This comes up only in the android browser.